# Characters in .glb exported to FBX for ReadyPlayer break material order 3.1

Tags: texturing, materials, .fbx

I downloaded my avatar in glb format but when I try exporting to FBX, the material order always gets mixed up. I am facing this issue only in blender 3.1 but not in the earlier version of blender

Comment: Sounds as if you should report it as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a bug menu.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: I had the same weird texture problem and found the correct steps here: https://rehtse-studio.medium.com/made-with-unity-using-blender-to-convert-ready-player-me-avatars-to-fbx-62af1f14b135 Ignore the bit about import into Unity. My ReadyPlayer glb to fbx export in Blender worked just fine as an FBX import test in Blender and perfect upload and animate in Mixamo.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me

1. Open Blender and delete everything (Cube, Camera, Light) from the “Scene Collection.”
2. Import the Ready Player download into Blender using File->Import->press on gLTF 2.0 (.glb/.gltf)
3. Save the project as a blend file first, and save it in the same folder where you have the GLB model.

(Step 4 is the only change from my multiple previous attempts that didn't work)

4. Once the blend file has been saved, go to File->External Data->press "Unpack Resources" and select "Use files in current directory (create when necessary)".
5. Go back to File->Export->and select FBX.
6. Before exporting, please ensure Path Mode is set to Copy and the button next to it is selected; it has to be blue.

Original Information Source:
Rehtse Studio "Made With Unity | Using Blender to Convert Ready Player Me Avatars to FBX"
URL: rehtse-studio.medium.com/made-with-unity-using-blender-to-convert-ready-player-me-avatars-to-fbx-62af1f14b135